# create an array of anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I am trying to get data from database for Google charts in my program. I would like to create an array of anonymous type (var) instead of repeating my code over and over again:

```
 public JsonResult GetChartData(int sID, int regionID)
    {

            var testPathOne = from p in _rep.GetMetricsData().GetLHDb().page_loads                                 
                              where p.t_3id == sID && p.test_path_id == 1
                              select new { time = p.time, created_at = p.created_at };

            var testPathTwo = from p in _rep.GetMetricsData().GetLHDb().page_loads
                              where p.t_3id == sID && p.test_path_id == 2
                              select new { time = p.time, created_at = p.created_at };

            var tOne = testPathOne.ToArray();
            var tTwo = testPathTwo.ToArray();
            var name = new { test1 = tOne, test2 = tTwo };
            return Json(name);
        }
```

i know that i will need a for loop so i can go through all the test path id's instead of hard coding them like this `p.test_path_id == 1`, but my question is how would i make this part dynamic `var name = new { test1 = tOne, test2 = tTwo };`

**Edit:**
I apologize, I would like to do something like this:

```
name is an array

for loop:
    testPath = query
    name.Add(testPath)
```

I hope that makes sense

Comment: What do you mean by "make this part dynamic"? Dynamic in what way? It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve. If you're looking for dynamic property names, you could potentially look at `ExpandoObject`, but I think you'd be better off building the JSON directly...

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just to double-check, `var` can only be used in situations where the compiler can fully determine **at compile time** the type represented by `var`. If the type cannot be determined until runtime, you might consider using `dynamic`, but I'm not sure how this fits in for this particular case.

Comment: I think he wants to return the two lists to be return in a single json.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a simple struct containing the `time` and `created_at`.  This way you will know the type and make your code, imo, more readable and maintainable.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I added a piece of psuedocode at the bottom of my post of what I am trying to achieve. I hope it makes sense :-S

Comment: Do you mean loop on value of "test_path_id" and than construct JSON like `{"test1"={}, "test2"={},...., "test1234"={}}` ?

Comment: yes Alexei, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution in this particular case would be to just give a name to the class that is currently anonymous.  While there are workarounds that you can use, when you need to start working really hard to use an anonymous type you probably shouldn't be using it.  It's there to make certain tasks quicker and easier; if that isn't happening then you are likely better off with a real class.

That solution would look something like this:

```
//Please give me a real name
public class ClassToBeRenamed
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

List<ClassToBeRenamed[]> myList = new List<ClassToBeRenamed[]>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
myList.Add((from p in _rep.GetMetricsData().GetLHDb().page_loads
            where p.t_3id == sID && p.test_path_id == i
            select new ClassToBeRenamed { Time = p.time, CreatedAt = p.created_at })
            .ToArray());
}
```

Having said all of that, it's still possible.

```
var myList = new[]{
                from p in _rep.GetMetricsData().GetLHDb().page_loads
                where p.t_3id == sID && p.test_path_id == 1
                select new { time = p.time, created_at = p.created_at }.ToArray()
}.ToList();

for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
{
    myList.Add(from p in _rep.GetMetricsData().GetLHDb().page_loads
                where p.t_3id == sID && p.test_path_id == i
                select new { time = p.time, created_at = p.created_at }.ToArray()
                );
}

var myArray = myList.ToArray();
```

If it's really, really important that you have an array, and not a list, then you could call `ToArray` on myList at the very end.  It's important that you start out with a list, and only convert it to an array at the end because Arrays have a fixed size once they are created.  You can mutate their contents, but you can't make them bigger or smaller.  A List on the other hand, is designed to mutate it's size over time, so it can start out with 0 or 1 items and then add items over time, which is important for us in this particular context.  (It's actually useful quite often, which is why it is frequently useful to use `List` over arrays.)

Comment: You have mixed to distinct list, which is not desirable here.

Comment: oh ok that makes sense. But about creating a separate class, did you mean create a class that only holds `time` and `created_at`? Could you elaborate on that little bit more? thanks

Comment: @SherCoder Yes, I do.  I've added a code snippet showing that method.

Comment: Thanks again. and yes it is important that I have an array. So I add ToArray instead of ToList but it says Array deos not contain a definition for Add function. How do I get around that?

Comment: You need to convert it to an array, from a list, at the end, not at the start.  I'll elaborate as to why in the answer.

Comment: thanks but my another question is what if i want to do something like this: testPaths.Add( `test1`= myquery )

Comment: I want to give it a name just like i am doing here: `var name = new { test1 = tOne, test2 = tTwo };`

Comment: And what compelling reason do you have for wanting that over an array like you ask for in your question?  It will be substantially harder to create, and also very hard to actually use.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using LINQ use foreach loops. You are more limited with LINQ.
Also define your ArrayLists at the beginning and add to them as you go.

```
var test1 = new ArrayList();
var test2 = new ArrayList();
foreach(PageLoad p in _rep.GetMetricsData().GetLHDb().page_loads)
{
    if(p.t_3id == sID)
    {
        var tr = new { time = p.time, created_at = p.created_at };
        switch(p.test_path_id) 
        {
            case 1: test1.Add(tr); break;
            case 2: test2.Add(tr); break;
        }
    }
}
return Json(new { test1, test2, });
```

You do not need to define the names of properties anonymous types because they default to the variable names.